# Run time permission in android tab with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my contains tab with viewpager fragments.  There are 3 tabs in the application.  I need different run time permission for each tabs.  I run application for first time permission for tab1 asks.  I clicked on tab2 no permission is asks.  If i click tab3 permission ask.  If i start application second time permission for tab2 ask.  How can i solve this ?

```
    mTab1 = new Tab1();
    mTab2 = new Tab2();
    mTab3 = new Tab3();
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(mTab1, tabTitles[0]);
    adapter.addFragment(mTab1, tabTitles[1]);
    adapter.addFragment(mTab1, tabTitles[2]);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

snippet for tab

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private List<ListAdapter.Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext = null;
    private static boolean mbPermission = false;
    private int mnCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Calls", "onCreate " + mbPermission);

        if( PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG){
          LoadViews();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS );
        } 
    }

        @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissionsList[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:{
                for( int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                    if( grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                        LoadViews();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", " Permitted NOT OK: " + permissionsList[i]);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("Calls", "onCreateView " + mbPermission);
        View Root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) Root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mAdapter = new ListAdapter(items, 0, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return Root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any code we can't guess the issue Have look How to create [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Use PageRefreshViewPager which is provided in the link below it will load only the current page which is visible into memory and 
your issue will be solved as viewpager loads two pages into memory by default

https://gist.github.com/r00786/0dc136a716e8027da33b08ea3154ade1

Comment: can you provide a small example

Comment: have provided in the gist

Comment: copy the pageRefreshViewpager into your project which is in the gist and the I have provided in the howtouse gist you just need to setOffscreenLimit to 0 and set the adapter of your viewpager that's it

Answer (score 1):

you have to write the permission code in the **activity**, **not in a fragment**.

write below viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); like this

```
 mTab1 = new Tab1();
    mTab2 = new Tab2();
    mTab3 = new Tab3();
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(mTab1, tabTitles[0]);
    adapter.addFragment(mTab1, tabTitles[1]);
    adapter.addFragment(mTab1, tabTitles[2]);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
if( PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG){
          LoadViews();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS );
        }
```